# Possible to mask an animated Movie Clip? Flash as3 cs4

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, mask, shadow

I have a simple animation set up - A background I have painted in P/Shop and a Sheep. 
The sheep is an animated movie clip - whose head turns and body moves.

What I need to happen is that when the sheep walks under a tree - he is in complete shadow - until he walks out from under the tree.

So far I managed to put the sheep under a shadow layer.. mask the shadow and use a rectangle which is aprox sheep size - it then moves along a tween teh same as the sheep.. It is quite clunky though and will take a fair amount of work reshape the mask shape each time to cover the exact sheep.. even then I won't be able to follow the animation exactly.

So, is there a way to have the animated sheep be a movie clip and a mask - so that he goes into full shadow everytime he passes under a tree.

Or is there another way to achieve this? Thx

Answer (score 1):

The problem is cacheAsBitmap property,

you must assign maskclip and your maskedclip property to cacheAsBitmap = true

For example:

```
maskmc.cacheAsBitmap = true;
myMaskedClip.cacheAsBitmap = true;
myMaskedClip.mask = maskmc;
```

I added sample fla file that you can check it here : [FLA](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53894534/demo-cs6.fla)

Comment: Hey.. Thanks for this. I ended getting rid of the problem, rather than trying to fix it.. Thanks all the same though.  My Flash CS5 won't allow me access to your file though.

Comment: cool, if it helps you can vote up and others can see it works, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your sheep on a layer in between the shadow and the background? Probably not because you want the sheep in front of the tree - 
Maybe you need to put a shadow element inside the sheep movie clip, and use a script to fade it in or out depending on hit test with the tree. 
You could add a duplicate copy of the sheep to be used as a mask, although a shadow would probably need softer edges than this kind of mask will give you.

Comment: Thanks for that - Maybe the shadow element could work. I'll look into how to create a hit area - but am rubbish at coding these things myself. If not, maybe I'll have to do it manually - ie - as he enters the frame in timeline, which matches the timeline where he walks under a tree - I just tween him darker..

Comment: I think I may have steeped to extra low levels of thickness.. I can simply tween the brightness as the sheep goes under the tree... Not quite the same as having the 'speckled' tree shadow - but probably good enough..